How to add a path to PATH that involves a variable that needs to be evaluated?
say I want to add the current directory to path. I need to run echo "export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)" >> ~/.bash_profile.
this expands $(pwd) like I wanted, but it also expands the $PATH which it shouldn't because it would ignore previous PATH exports in my ~/.bash_profile.
Is there a way to expand pwd but not PATH?

Why are you creating a command to call to modify your .bash_profile instead of just editing it once with your favorite editor?

because this is a component of automation?

Use
printf '%s\n' "PATH+=':$(pwd)'" >> ~/.bash_profile


+= to append to the variable.
PATH is already exported so you don't need to do it again
Why is printf better than echo?


Simply escape the expansion operator $ using \$.
